# How to run multile device under same paho-mqtt script

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am writing a script which will log more than one device with different credentials using paho-mqtt. All the client is running in the same address and with the same port. If I change the username and pass then I get the different feeds depending upon the credentials. It's working fine if I write for different devices different script. But I want to log all the devices in on_connet. I have written the script but it's working only for one device. Here is the script:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time, json, threading, logging,ssl 

clients=[
   {"ursername":"username1","password": 'password1'},
   {"ursername":"username2","password":'password2'},
   {"ursername":"username3","password":'password3'}
]
nclients=len(clients)
run = True

def Create_connections():
   for i in range(nclients):
      t=int(time.time())
      client_id = "client" + str(t)
      client = mqtt.Client(client_id)
      
      username = credentials[i]["ursername"]
      password = credentials[i]["password"]
      
      client.on_log=on_log
      client.on_connect = on_connect
      client.on_subscribe=on_subscribe
      client.on_message = on_message
      client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
      print("connecting to broker")
      
      client.tls_set("CXXXXX.crt", tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
      client.tls_insecure_set(True)
      client.username_pw_set(username, password)
      client.loop_start()
      client.connect("XXXXX", XXXX, XX)
      print("Loop pass ")


def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
   print("message:" + str(buf))
   print("userdata:" + str(userdata))

   
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
   msg="message received",str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
   print(msg)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   print("Connected with result code:"+str(rc))
   client.subscribe('v3/+/devices/+/up')


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
   pass

def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
   print("mid: " + str(mid) + '\n')

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))

mqtt.Client.connected_flag=False
no_threads=threading.active_count()
print("current threads =",no_threads)
print("Creating  Connections ",nclients," clients")

   
Create_connections()
```

Response

```
current threads = 1
Creating  Connections  2  clients
____________________________________________________________________________
client01597648398
<paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x7f73c0a5b1d0>
username1
connecting to broker
message:Sending CONNECT (u1, p1, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'client01597648398'
userdata:None
message:Received CONNACK (0, 0)
userdata:None
Connected with result code:0
message:Sending SUBSCRIBE (d0, m1) [(b'XX/+/devices/+/XX', 0)]
userdata:None
message:Received SUBACK
userdata:None
Subscribed: 1 (0,)
message:Sending PINGREQ
userdata:None
message:Received PINGRESP
userdata:None
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the output when starting your program? I am interested in the connection result codes for the different clients and it might be interesting as well if they get disconnected by the broker so you might want to print the result code within `on_disconnect` as well

Comment: @Odysseus I have uploaded the response. Its seems after getting the first successful response. Its not getting looped.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies here:

```
while run:
    client.loop_forever()
```

`loop_forever()` is a blocking call which will only return when the associated client is disconnected:

> This is a blocking form of the network loop and will not return until the client calls disconnect(). It automatically handles reconnecting. [paho-mqtt](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#network-loop)

So your other clients never get initialized/connected. You might want to use `loop_start` instead - this will use a separate thread to handle communication for every client:

```
def Create_connections():
   for i in range(nclients):
      # ...
      client.loop_start()
      client.connect("XXXXXXXXXX", XXXX, XX)

# ...
Create_connections()

while run:
   pass
```

Comment: I have tried even that but the problem there lies is I am not getting continuous logging it connects with both of my devices and the script ends.

Comment: @Piyush When using `loop_start` you don't want to call this within your endless loop but only once for each client. Then you need to call your `while run` loop after your `CreateConnection()` call - otherwise you program will simply exit

Comment: I have already removed the endless loop. But its not continuously logging the data. Its getting connected and then it didnt logged

Comment: @Piyush Is the `on_subscribe` method entered after your client connected? Please provide your updated code by appending it to your question

Comment: I think I found my mistake. In the end of script I need to write `while run: pass`